# inline javascript function not detecting script loaded via code

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
<script src="some.js">
<script>
afunction(); //this function is in some.js
</script>
```

Then I thought to improve the page speed of the site and load some.js like this

```
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "some.js;
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

and now the function doesn't exist and i get an error.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: have u tried to use `<body onload="">` ?

Comment: you're missing a quote on element.src = 'some.js';

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Your script may be loaded, but not executed.

Comment: If your script is in the head, then the body may not exist when it runs. Add the new script to the head, which must exist at that moment.

Comment: thank you for the above - sorry for the syntax errors - that was just my haste. I have moved the script to the head on your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out above, some of the errors you might be encountering are perhaps due to missing " and so on. Assuming that you have every syntax correct, this approach will fail because how HTML parsing happens:

Assuming that you've got this code in the `<HEAD>` section:

When the parser (in your browser) reads the file stream where you've got this code, it is going to construct the DOM as it is doing so. This means that when it gets to the point in your code where you are telling it to append as a child your script node element to the body, it is going to fail because document.body does not exist yet and this is an error.

Assuming that you've got this code in the `<BODY>` section:

Then by the mere that you have attached a SCRIPT node element to the DOM does not imply that the file has been loaded by the Javascript engine and processed the content of "some.js". Therefore, when "aFunction" is called, it is undefined.

Finally, i do not think you gain anything peformance-wise by loading your script after your document has loaded.

Comment: I think this is the issue. Is there a way to get the browser to delay inline javascript?

Comment: delaying can be done like how others have mentioned: example, wait for a "later" event like Window.onload or, document.body.onload. Or, you can use setTimeout in a wrapper script to delay the execution of the aFunction.

Answer (score 0):

**There are many Syntax Error in your Script**

But the answer to the actuall question is `window.onload`

```
<script>
     window.onload = function () {
         afunction();
     }
</script>
```

**Syntax Need Correction**

*1) Close Script Tag* :

```
<script src="some.js"></script>
<script>
     afunction(); //this function is in some.js
</script>
```

*2) Missing double quote(")*

```
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "some.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to be written globally like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
});

afunction () {
}
```

in 'some.js' script.
and access tat function using div tag.

```
<div id = 'a' onClick='afunction()'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by calling the function too soon after the node has been appended. All you need is a timeout.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.createElement("script");
elem.src = "scripts/test.js";
elem.type="text/javascript";
//
 function runTest()
  { document.body.appendChild(elem);
    setTimeout("alertThis('This is a test')",50); 
  }
window.onload=runTest;
</script>
```

The external js for this example says

```
function alertThis(msg) { alert(msg); }
```

It runs correctly in all browsers.